# Puppeteer blocking the event loop

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

- Puppeteer version: 1.1.0
- Platform / OS version: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
- Node.js version: v8.17.0

```js
const express = require('express');
const blocked = require('blocked-at')
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;
const URL = "https://www.huffingtonpost.in/entry/india-drops-10-spots-democracy-index_in_5e27ebc3c5b67d8874a92ab1"
let browser;

app.get('execute', async  (req, res) =>{
    page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(URL, {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
        timeout: 3000000
    })
});

app.listen(PORT, async () => {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch(CHROME_LAUNCHER_OPTIONS);
    return;
})

blocked((time, stack, {type, resource}) => {
 console.log(`Blocked for ${time}ms, operation started here:`, stack,"TYPE :",type)
}, {resourcesCap: 100})
```

We have an express server, which will create a browser instance. When a request comes in, we are creating and rendering the page to get the content of the page.

**What is the expected result?** I expected to process the request in parallel

```
#!/bin/bash
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:3000/execute' &
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:3000/execute' &
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:3000/execute' &
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:3000/execute' &
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:3000/execute' &
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:3000/execute' &
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:3000/execute' &
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:3000/execute' &
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:3000/execute' &
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:3000/execute' &
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:3000/execute' &
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:3000/execute' &
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:3000/execute' &
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:3000/execute' &
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:3000/execute' &
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:3000/execute' &
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:3000/execute' &
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:3000/execute' &
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:3000/execute' &
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:3000/execute' &
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:3000/execute' &
wait
```

**What happens instead?**
it seems the requests are blocked due to some WebSocket connection.[image]

Comment: it looks like you wanted to file this over on https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues - this is Stackoverflow, not a bug tracker.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have added an issue there also.

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/5333) the issue in question for those curious

Answer (score 0):

The websocket related function you see blocking the event loop is CDP (Chrome Debugger Protocol) traffic. That is how puppeteer communicates with the headless browser. Not much you can do about that apart from getting it off the main thread.

I'm using [Piscina](https://github.com/piscinajs/piscina) to run a pool of workers. It's pretty simple, it only added about 12 LOC to my project. One thing to watch out for: use an initialization function to create the browser instance (`puppeteer.launch()`), see the Piscina github readme [Delaying Availability of Workers section](https://github.com/piscinajs/piscina#delaying-availability-of-workers) for details. Otherwise the worker thread may be set to ready before it can start doing work.

I'm using one browser instance per thread ( calling `puppeteer.launch()` in each worker thread ) based on [this post from people that seem well versed](https://docs.browserless.io/blog/2018/06/04/puppeteer-best-practices.html#4-parallelize-with-browsers-not-pages). They advise to:

> Parallelize with browsers, not pages

I'm using this approach to write an HTML to PDF conversion service that exposes a JSON API. So far no blocking of the event loop with expected load. I'm experimenting with the ideal number of worker thread to CPU core ratio. Most time is spent waiting for external CSS requests to complete.